# Need help installing Imagemagick on Centos 6.4

Tags: centos, centos-6

Helo guys.

I am trying to install Imagemagick on centos 6.4 server using this tutorial

http://www.tecmint.com/install-imagemagick-in-linux/

The problem I had to face is that when I run peck install imagick command. The progress starts but at the end it says make command not found.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Run

```
yum install make
```

Make is also part of the "Development Tools" group, so you can run

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

to install it and other packages that may prove useful when installing packages from source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to correct the below command it is yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y

Comment: Anyway your answer helped me.

Comment: @user2354128 Thanks for the correction; I updated the answer.